# g:timeZoneSelect in Grails 2.0

Tags: grails

I am using the following in a .gsp file

```
<g:timeZoneSelect name="timezone" value="${user?.timezone}"/>
```

But the ending list given for selection has many, many repeating values for each timezone for example I count at least 14 choices for:

```
MST, Mountain Standard Time -7:00
```

Am I doing something wrong or is this a bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the source for the controller, it's because they are rendering a slot for each timezone region.  For example:

```
<option value="America/Boise" >MST, Mountain Standard Time -7:0.0</option>
<option value="America/Cambridge_Bay" >MST, Mountain Standard Time -7:0.0</option>
<option value="America/Chihuahua" >MST, Mountain Standard Time -7:0.0</option>
<option value="America/Dawson_Creek" >MST, Mountain Standard Time -7:0.0</option>
<option value="America/Denver" >MST, Mountain Standard Time -7:0.0</option>
<option value="America/Edmonton" >MST, Mountain Standard Time -7:0.0</option>
<option value="America/Hermosillo" >MST, Mountain Standard Time -7:0.0</option>
<option value="America/Inuvik" >MST, Mountain Standard Time -7:0.0</option>
```

I would say this is a bug.  I think it should either include the city names, or collapse repeat values, because there is no way to differentiate them.

[There is a JIRA open for this](http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-6590).  Please vote.